# MySQL varchar contains

Tags: mysql

I am trying to take in a list of indexes and then use them to set a varchar to a certain string to filter on my database. Problem is I have tried using the Like command:

```
Declare StateList varchar(150);
Declare States varchar(150);
set @StateList = State;
set @States = '';

if (@StateList Like '%1%')then set @States := Concat(@States, '1,2');
elseif(@StateList Like '%2%')then set @States := Concat(@States,'3');
elseif(@StateList Like '%3%')then set @States := Concat(@States, '4,5');
end if;
select @StateList,@States;
```

This when I input **`123`** will return just 3 when I want it to return 1 through 5.

Then I tried

```
Declare StateList varchar(150);
Declare States varchar(150);
set @StateList = State;
set @States = '';

if CONTAINS(@StateList, '1')then set @States := Concat(@States, '1,2,');
elseif CONTAINS(@StateList ,'2')then set @States := Concat(@States,'3');
elseif CONTAINS(@StateList,'3')then set @States := Concat(@States, '4,5');
end if;
select @StateList,@States;
```

Which returned nothing, I'm confused as I though that the first solution would have worked?

Any suggestions would be great! 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Does MySQL have the function CONTAINS()?

Comment: Probably not, it was something I came across while searching for a solution. Don't think it is in MySQL but I tried it anyway.

Comment: Everything about this question suggests a [database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) problem. Are you sure your schema is properly relational?

Comment: The database is fine, what happens is the user gets given options open, closed, pending. These are then given values of 1,2,3 but some states may have sub states, I am trying to get these values when the query is run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use separate `IF's`, `if,elseif` means that only one of the can be true. Try something like this:

```
if (@StateList Like '%1%')then set @States := Concat(@States, '1,2');
end if;
if(@StateList Like '%2%')then set @States := Concat(@States,'3');
end if;
if(@StateList Like '%3%')then set @States := Concat(@States, '4,5');
end if;
```

Comment: Right you are! I can believe I did not see what I had done, the fact that the first if didn't return the result had thrown me off. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @sagi that IFs should be separated, however I'm wondering that result is '3' and not '1,2'. Maybe you can try this function http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_instr
So the code will be:

```
if (INSTR(@StateList, '1') > 0)then set @States := Concat(@States, '1,2');
end if;
...
```

Comment: Yeah @sagi solution actually works though, but I was also confused by this so I just assumed that the it being an elseif wasn't the problem